# Why this simple C code giving Bus Error?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// Here i declared global variables.
int repLetters[26];
char* letters1;

static void makeRepLetters()
{
    printf("enter makeRep");
    int i =0;
    for(;i<26;i++)  
        repLetters[i] =0;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++) {
        repLetters[((letters1[i]) - 97)] +=1; 
    }
}      

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=0,num =10;
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <letters>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    //letters1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* strlen( argv[1]));
    //strcpy(letters1,argv[1]); 
    letters1 = argv[1];
    printf("\n letters1 = %s",letters1);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\ncheck test\n");

    makeRepLetters();
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        printf("\n %c occured %d tyms",i+97,repLetters[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

After printing "check test", I get a bus error. `makeRepLetters` is not getting called. I tried changing many things but could not get it to work.

Comment: Don't suppose you ever allocated memory for `letters1`.

Comment: @chris i did it by allocating memory to it, then also got the same error at the same place. you can see that i have commented the memory allocation code and directly make letters1 point to argv[1];

Comment: Note that since the message you print in `makeRepLetters()` does not end with a newline and you don't `fflush(stdout)`, the output won't appear before your program crashes.  If you want to see diagnostic output, make sure it ends with a newline (and even then, if you send the output to a file, you want to do `fflush(stdout)` or `fflush(0)` after printing).

Answer (score 1):

The crash is most likely here:

```
repLetters[((letters1[i]) - 97)] +=1;
```

What if `letters1` doesn't contain 26 characters? You are now accessing an array out of bounds.

The only way to know for sure, is to run your program in a debugger (which you *always* should do when you have a crash).

Comment: Or what if the value of letters1[i] is less than 97?  Then you're using a negative index into repLetters.

Comment: Or what if "abc...xyz" isn't valued at 97...122?